# php urlencode encodes wrong?

Tags: php, urlencode

If I try to encode the url

```
http://herthabsc.de/index.php?id=3631&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=13144&cHash=9ef2e9ee006fb16188ebf764232a0ba9
```

with `urlencode()` or `http_build_query()` it gives me the result

```
http%3A%2F%2Fherthabsc.de%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D3631%26%23038%3Btx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D%3D13144%26%23038%3BcHash%3D9ef2e9ee006fb16188ebf764232a0ba9
```

But that's not what it should be. Is there a known bug? Or problems in use with wordpress?

Comment: What do you expect it to be? That's an encoded URL. Do you only wish to encode the querystring part of that URL?

Comment: the function works as described in the manual, it's your expectations that are wrong.

Comment: it actually has to be http%3A//herthabsc.de/index.php%3Fid%3D3631%26tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D%3D13144%26cHash%3D9ef2e9ee006fb16188ebf764232a0ba9

Comment: And why is that so? The manual says: "Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits" - therefore replacing the slashes with %2F is the expected behavior.

Comment: No I mean the & symbol should be %26 and its %26%23038%3B

Comment: Comes out as `http%3A%2F%2Fherthabsc.de%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D3631%26tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D%3D13144%26cHash%3D9ef2e9ee006fb16188ebf764232a0ba9` when I run it through `urlencode()`. Show us your actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've double encoded the URL.  Running `urldecode()` on your output string is giving me the following: `http://herthabsc.de/index.php?id=3631&#038;tx_ttnews[tt_news]=13144&#038;cHash=9ef2e9ee006fb16188ebf764232a0ba9`

**EDIT:**
try the following

```
urlencode(html_entity_decode('http://herthabsc.de/index.php?id=3631&#038;tx_ttnews[tt_news]=13144&#038;cHash=9ef2e9ee006fb16188ebf764232a0ba9'));
```

Comment: yes, probably the poster is viewing the link in a browser, where it shows &#038 as a single ampersand character

Comment: I'm doing this in Google Chrome