# %22 (double quotes) added to url out of nowhere

Tags: php, url, tinymce

I'm making a mail programm that wil be used to mail newsletters to customers, in the newsletters will be images and links. When I tested it on localhost everything worked fine and the links worked. However when I uploaded it to my website the links and image paths won't work anymore.

For some reason it adds %22 (which I found out are double quotes ") to the links and paths so the link I mailed looks like this:

`/%22http//www.mywebsite.com/%22`

And the image path looks like this:

`%22http//www.mywebsite.com/content/someimage.jpg/%22`

I'm using TinyMCE to edit the newsletter and I've tried `relative_urls : false` and `convert_urls : false` but that does nothing. I don't think this is a TinyMCE issue but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

I have no clue what is causing this so if anyone knows what it going on it would be great!

Update:
I've checked my code and looked at the html of the text being send in the mail and there are no double quotes around the link at any time so my guess is that it is a server issue.

Comment: how are you building your urls? looks like you're treating them as string (the `%22` encapsulates your urls)

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I just add the link with an option in TinyMCE, but when I look at the html of the newsletter its a simple `<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">mywebsite</a>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem with `magic_quotes` Check your phpinfo() to see if it is turned off. If you are able to turn it off You have to disable it in your php.ini.

You can test if it's enabled or disabled with the following code:

```
<?php
echo "Magic quotes is ";
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  echo "enabled.";
} else {
  echo "disabled";
}
?>
```

Another fix could be to use `stripslashes()` to remove the slashes. This most likely will solve the problem.

Read the docs about `stripslashes()` [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

A quick example:

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

**Edit: another thing you can try is to use `html_entity_encode()`.**

An example:

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```

info [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Another SO answer. for `html_entity_encode()` in urls
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001006/1379394

Comment: how do you know he's using php? (don't want to be an ass, your answer is the correct one, just curious about how you took your guess...)

Comment: Because he added the php tag.

Comment: No problem. Happens to me too sometimes.

Comment: @KeesSonnema I tested the magic quotes and they were disabled. I know the stripslashes would have worked with other prgramms but if I use the stripslashes on my whole newsletter I can't type any double quotes anywhere anymore so that isn't really an option here.

Comment: Magic quotes does not add double quotes, does it?

Comment: I could be. but I read something about an error which looked like this one. and it was a Magic_quotes problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no access to your php.ini file,the easiest way could be adding this to your 
.htaccess file:

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off