# Using php to echo a dynamic URL correctly

Tags: php

I am using php and conditional code to give a dynamic url to a photo. The result should read as http://example.com/biophotos/1.jpg. But instead I am getting 
http://example.com/%22http://example.com/biophotos/1.jpg%22

How can I force it to just give the one url and without the %22 space on the end?

```
if ($emresult[0]['photo'] = "y") {
echo '<img class=\"alignright\" src=\"http://example.com/biophotos/' .
$theID . '.jpg" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">';
}
else {
echo 'There is no author photo.';
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't escape double quotes when using single quotes for your echo.

Comment: That did the trick removing the escaping. Thanks! However, it doesn't give me the else "There is no photo" if the condition is not met. Do you see an obvious reason why? $theID is variable capturing the user's ID from a previous page.

Comment: nevermind. I needed == instead of =  in the if

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason in escaping double quotes when your using single quotes.

```
echo '<img class="alignright" src="http://example.com/biophotos/' . $theID . '.jpg" width="150" height="150" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I agree with @slik, you also might want to look into [%22 (double quotes) added to url out of nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187673/22-double-quotes-added-to-url-out-of-nowhere)

Check if magic quotes is on in your php.ini file. You can look into `html_entity_encode()` to encode the %22 as a slash.